# How to read packed structures using ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes

Is there a way in python to unpack C structures created using `#pragma pack(x)` or `__attribute__((packed))` using structs?

Alternatively, how to determine the manner in which python struct handles padding?

Comment: Is [`Structure._pack_`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.Structure._pack_) what you're after?

Comment: Indeed that works for ctypes, anything for struct's?

Comment: Oops, sorry for misreading. The tag confused me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) class.

It is flexible in terms of byte order (big vs. little endian) and alignment (packing). See [*Byte Order, Size, and Alignment*](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment).  It defaults to *native* byte order (pretty much meaning however python was compiled).

**Native example**

C:

```
struct foo {
    int  bar;
    char t;
    char x;
}
```

Python:

```
struct.pack('IBB', bar, t, x)
```

Comment: `No padding is added when using non-native size and alignment, e.g. with ‘<’, ‘>’, ‘=’, and ‘!’.` Damn, forgot to read that :P It works! Thanks! :D