# Best way to design c like struct in python

Tags: python, c, class, struct

First of all, I just started python yet I really tried hard to find what fits for me. The thing I am going to do is a simple file system for linux but to tell the truth I don't even sure if it is achievable with python. So I need a bit help of here.

I tried to create a class structure and named tuples (one at a time which one fits) and I decided classes would be better for me. The thing is I couldn't read byte by byte because of the size of my class was 888 while in C it was 44 (I used sys.getsizeof() there) It will be more understand what I want to achieve with some code below

For this structure

```c
struct sb{
    int inode_bitmap;
    int data_bitmap[10];
};
```

I used

```
#SUPER BLOCK
class sb(object):
    __slots__ = ['inode_bitmap', 'data_bitmap'] #REDUCE RAM USAGE
    def __init__(bruh, inode_bitmap, data_bitmap):
        bruh.inode_bitmap = inode_bitmap
        bruh.data_bitmap = [None] * 10 #DEFINITION OF ARRAY
```

Everything was fine till I read it

```c
    FILE * fin = fopen("simplefs.bin", "r");
        struct inode slash;

    fseek(fin, sizeof(struct sb), SEEK_SET);
    fread(&slash,sizeof(slash),1,fin);
```

```py
fin = open("simplefs.bin", "rb")


slash = inode

print("pos:", fin.tell())
contents = fin.read(sys.getsizeof(sb))
print(contents)
```

Since actual file size was smth like 4800 however when I was reading the size was approximately 318

I am pretty aware that python is not C but I am just doing some experiments if it is achievable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - struct / ctypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20066176/python-struct-ctypes)

Comment: Try using a [`collections.nametuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) — they should be much smaller.

Comment: Is your question how to design a data structure or how to serialize a Python object to a file?

Comment: "I couldn't read byte by byte because of the size of my class was 888 while in C it was 44" - I don't understand: what exactly is it that you are trying to `read byte by byte`? Where did `simplefs.bin` come from, and what problem are you trying to solve by reading it in like this, exactly? Why not actually parse and interpret the file?

Comment: @mkrieger1 the exact thing I want is creating a structure then writing it to a file as binary then read it but it seems like python read the whole file and put the pointer to the end, here I have multiple problems to summarize 
1. create a structure,
2. write the structure as binary to a file
3. read the binary file and convert to utf-8

Comment: @KarlKnechtel sorry I am pretty new to this platform forgive my foolish topic, I used pickle to dump the data as binary and write it to a file https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/85nST5QJVB/      here I am trying to write my classes (which are structures I tried to create) then write to a file as binary and according to my output it is worked so far so good but then when I want to read like the C code given above I couldn't manage to do it

Comment: If you pickled it before writing it to a file, you have to unpickle it again after reading the raw data. You cannot simply use the raw data as a class instance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot design a struct and then try to read/write it to the file and expect it to be binary identical. If you want to parse any binary data, you have module `struct` that allows you to interpret the data you have read as `int`, `float` and a dozen of other formats. Still you have to write the formats manually. In your particular case:

```
import struct

with ('datafile.dat') as fin :
    raw_data = fin.read()

data = struct.unpack_from( '11I', raw_data )  # 11 integers
inode_bitmap = data[0]
data_bitmap = data[1:]
```

Or something along the lines...

Comment: It makes sense but I don't know my structure size and before I do the reading operation I want the code to do that for me (I found out the size given above from my C code, I couldn't get the same result from python)